# Generate random number in Laravel

Tags: php, string, random, laravel

Please am working on a Project on Laravel and I wanted to Generate a Random Number in this format: one character in any position order and the rest integers. Example: C87465398745635, 87474M745436475, 98487464655378J8 etc. and this is my Controller:

```
    function generatePin( $number ) {
    $pins = array();
    for ($j=0; $j < $number; $j++) { 
        $string = str_random(15);
        $pin = Pin::where('pin', '=', $string)->first();
        if($pin){
            $j--;
        }else{
            $pins[$j] = $string;
        }
    }



    return $pins;
}
```

But it seems to be Generating something else like this: ZsbpEKw9lRHqGbv, i7LjvSiHgeGrNN8, pyJEcjhjd3zu9Su I have tried all I could but no success, Please any helping solution will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: The title of the question is misleading, it is asking about a random number, but question is clearly about a random string

Comment: `Str::random(4);` In laravel there `Str` class for string, `use Illuminate\Support\Str;`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to generate the random string like you said, replace:

```
$string = str_random(15);
```

with

```
// Available alpha caracters
$characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

// generate a pin based on 2 * 7 digits + a random character
$pin = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999)
    . mt_rand(1000000, 9999999)
    . $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];

// shuffle the result
$string = str_shuffle($pin);
```

Edit:

Before, the code wasn't generating a random alpha character all the time. Thats because Laravel's `str_random` generates a random alpha-numeric string, and sometimes that function returned a numeric value ([see docs](http://laravel.com/api/function-str_random.html)).

Comment: Thanks this works and give me these as results: F2360463118, 54475708163, 8N182992222, 4629231O991, 1V387422817 But what is missing and my observations are: 1. The Second Generated Number here (54475708163) did not have any Alpha-Character which might mean some will add the Alpha-Character while some wouldn't which is not good or inline and 2. I want the Numbers to be 14 Digits and one Alphabet making it 15 altogether instead of the 9 Digits and 1 Alpha-Character we have here Thanks, I really do Appreciate!

Comment: 3. Please I hope this method will not allow a repeatation of each generated Number because this Generated Numbers will be given out to different People at the same time and if it repeats there will be conflict of user's given Generated Number. Please how safe is mt_rand and at which interval will the Numbers repeat itself again? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer. As for your comments: 
1. Sorry, that was true. I was using, like you, the `str_random` function of Laravel and that function generates a random alpha-numeric string. 
2. Sorry, corrected that in the updated answer. 
3. I would say its very unlikely that this method generates the same value BUT it is possible. If you want a truly secure generator I advise you to take a look at this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Comment: Thanks you have done so much and have reduced my brain cracking. It all worked fine, But if I may to use the Secure Openssl Random Pseudo Bytes that you just recommended here in my code above, How will it be implemented? Thanks once again!

Comment: The answer should use `random_int` rather than `mt_rand`, and should not use `str_shuffle`.  `random_int` was introduced in PHP 7 and uses a cryptographic random generator, something that is important if strings have to be hard to guess.  Strings generated by solutions that involve `time()`, `microtime()`, `uniqid()`, `rand()`, `mt_rand()`, `str_shuffle()`, and `array_rand()`, are much more predictable and are unsuitable if the random string will serve as a password, a bearer credential, a session identifier, a "confirmation code", or another secret value.

Answer (score 9):

This should give you random number between 2 & 50.

```
$randomId       =   rand(2,50);
```

Answer (score 8):

use the function rand.

Example:

```php
 echo rand(0, 99999);
```

Answer (score 6):

In laravel there is Str class already aliases in Bootstrap

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
//...
echo Str::upper(Str::random(16)); // J1NMDQAFD5LM9DK5
```

#### Create manualy

Generate random number

```
echo generateRandomString(6) // Ex j4nDqQRiYafD
```

#### Implementation

```
function generateRandomString(int $n=0)
{
  $al = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'
  , 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
  'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
  'F','G','H','I','J','K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
  'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
  '0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

  $len = !$n ? random_int(7, 12) : $n; // Chose length randomly in 7 to 12

  $ddd = array_map(function($a) use ($al){
    $key = random_int(0, 60);
    return $al[$key];
  }, array_fill(0,$len,0));
  return implode('', $ddd);
}
```

Using [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function

> range — Create an array containing a range of elements
> Create an array containing a range of elements.

Using [array_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function

> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries. It uses a pseudo random number generator that is not suitable for cryptographic purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `$number` you pass on generatePin is the length of pin:

```
function generatePin( $number ) {
    // Generate set of alpha characters
    $alpha = array();
    for ($u = 65; $u <= 90; $u++) {
        // Uppercase Char
        array_push($alpha, chr($u));
    }

    // Just in case you need lower case
    // for ($l = 97; $l <= 122; $l++) {
    //    // Lowercase Char
    //    array_push($alpha, chr($l));
    // }

    // Get random alpha character
    $rand_alpha_key = array_rand($alpha);
    $rand_alpha = $alpha[$rand_alpha_key];

    // Add the other missing integers
    $rand = array($rand_alpha);
    for ($c = 0; $c < $number - 1; $c++) {
        array_push($rand, mt_rand(0, 9));
        shuffle($rand);
    }

    return implode('', $rand);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rand()` function to generate a random number.
You can also create some characters and prefix the `rand()` with it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create custom helper functions,**

by default the function will result in random string but if you want to generate only numbers just change parameter $type = int , example:
str_random(10, 'int');

```html
if (!function_exists('str_random')) {

   /** * Generate a Random String / Number.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Str;
    * @param type is INT or STR as default ;
    */
   function str_random(int $length = 10, string $type = 'str')
   {
      if (strtolower($type) === 'int') {
         $characters = '0123456789';
         $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
         $randomString = '';
         for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
         }
         return $randomString;
      }
      return Str::random($length);
   }
}
```

Dont forget to add this above your line of code

***use Illuminate\Support\Str;***